# How to get time counter from this web link to C# from

Tags: javascript, c#-3.0, webbrowser-control

http://www.tumangobajito.com/auctions/Blackberry-9360-Blanco-484

I have used WebBrowser control to navigate this link, but there is javascript error, so I cannot see the timer working.
Is there anyway for me to get this timer to a textbox in C# form ?

Answer (score 0):

The timer is being compared against an internal end-time field. You could attempt to reverse engineer the scripts and see if that data is something you have access to (there is 8 Javascript files active so I'll let you take a look).

Another method would be to use C# to download the page.  Then parse the data to look only for what is needed.

```
<div id="timer_484" class="timer countdown" title="1341363012">
CAPTURE THE DATA HERE
</div>
```

If you're needing the times from different pages, you'll have to modify your parser to fit accordingly.  Once you have that data though, you could write your own countdown timer (if that's the route you're taking with this).